# Help for understanding a proof that two endomorphisms coincide iff they have similar representative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

> Given a vector space $V$ over a field $K$, and $f,g\in End(V)$, let $A=[\alpha_{ij}]$ be the representative matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $B=\{\underline a_1, \underline a_2, \cdots, \underline a_n\}$ and let $A'=[\alpha'_{ij}]$ be the representative matrix of $g$ with respect to the basis $B'=\{\underline a'_1, \underline a'_2, \cdots, \underline a'_n\}.$
>
> We have $f=g$ iff $A=CA'C^{-1}$, where $C=[\gamma_{ij}]$ is the representative matrix of $h\in Aut(V)$ with respect to $B$, such that $h(\underline a_i)=\underline a'_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$.

I have some notes with the following proof, which I'm failing to grasp for the absence of explanations

[image]

I don't understand the second equality, and the following ones, which are similar in nature

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of a linear transformation $\varphi$ with respect to basis $B=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ has $\varphi(a_i)$, coordinated in $B$, as its $i$th column. 
To verify this, observe that $a_i$ coordinated in $B$ is just the $n$-tuple $e_i$ of scalars having $1$ in the $i$th coordinate and $0$ elsewhere, and that if a matrix $M$ has columns $m_1,\dots,m_n$, we get $M\cdot e_i=m_i$.

So that, in the exercise, we have the coordinates of $h(a_k)$ as the $k$th column of $C$:
$$[h(a_k)]_B=[h]_B[a_k]_B=Ce_k=(k\,\text{th column of }C)=\pmatrix{\gamma_{1k}\\ \vdots\\ \gamma_{nk}}$$
So that, $h(a_k)\ =\ \sum_i\gamma_{ik}a_i$.

Similarly, apply the same for $f$.

---

Note that a matrix multiplication on the right can be executed *columnwise*, in that $M\cdot[u_1\,|\,\dots\,|\,u_n]\ =\ [Mu_1\,|\,\dots\,|\,Mu_n]$, so we have
$$AC=[f(a'_1)\,|\,\dots\,|\,f(a'_n)]_B$$
On the other hand, $CA'=C\cdot[f(a'_1)\,|\,\dots\,|\,f(a'_n)]_{B'}$, while $C\pmatrix{\vartheta_1\\ \vdots\\ \vartheta_n}=\left[\sum_i\vartheta_ia'_i\right]_{B}$. 
Putting together,
$CA'=[f(a'_1)\,|\,\dots\,|\,f(a'_n)]_B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have just one more doubt about the part on $g$: isn't the equality $g(a_k')=\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{jk}'a_j'$ valid with respect to basis $B'$, as in, we're using $g(a_k')=A'\cdot a_j'$? On the other hand, the proof subsequently uses $a_j'=h(a_j)=C\cdot a_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma_{ij}a_i$, but isn't this with respect to basis $B$?

Comment: Sorry if it is a silly doubt, but I'm self-studying and struggling with this, I'd appreciate it if you could help me once more